# Dual command in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

"I am trying to achieve dual command in big query"

"I tried using the temp tables but not able to achieve it"

Oracle query: SELECT LEVEL - 1 F FROM
DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2

"I expect the output in below format "
F
1
2

I have salary table with salaries : 50$ and 200$

I want to have duplicate of each row : 50$ ,-50$,200$ and -200$ is the output which i am expecting like 4 rows in total

Comment: BigQuery DOES NOT support CONNECT BY - meantime if you can formulate your question in sense of what you have as an input data and what you expect as an output - we can try to help you. Ideally you should also provide what you tried by yourself - usually (even it is in many cases not even close to what will be the answer) it helps in understanding your case better. Anyway - good simple example along with explaining the logic is short way to get good answer

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant : updated the question . I looking to have the duplicate of each row . For example my table contains contains 100 rows i need 200 rows for each transaction where i have case statements to write both debit and credit transactions where the net sale amount should be zero . hope you got it

Comment: provide simplified but specific example of initial and then expected data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
SELECT
1
from (
select SESSION_USER())
```

to return a resultset with just one row.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be what you're looking for but it'll do the job as `SESSION_USER()` didn't work for me.

Here's the query :

```
WITH DUMMY AS(SELECT 1) -- Leave this as it is
SELECT TRUE -- Do what you want here
FROM DUMMY
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. I used it to test the current_date() function as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Since BigQuery doesn't support CONNECT BY clause and since you want to get a positive and negative values from your data, you could try using a simple query like this one:

```
SELECT my_value FROM `project.dataset.table`
UNION ALL
SELECT -my_value FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Notice the `-` in the second query as it'll give you negative values.

Hope it helps.